# ObservableInt not updating in BindingAdapter

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have this observable int with proper setter and getter on my POJO class object:

```
private ObservableInt pressure = new ObservableInt();

public ObservableInt getPressure()
{
    return pressure;
}

public void setPressure(ObservableInt pressure)
{
    this.pressure = pressure;
    setPressureValidation(isPressureValid());
}
```

To use this pressure variable on a EditText I had to create this adapters:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
public static void bindIntegerInText(AppCompatEditText editText, ObservableInt value)
{
    editText.setText(String.valueOf(value.get()));

    // Set the cursor to the end of the text
    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
}

@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
public static int getIntegerFromBinding(TextView view)
{
    String string = view.getText().toString();

    return string.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(string);
}
```

Now, I have this function to check if pressure is valid or not:

```
public boolean isPressureValid()
{
    return ( (pressure.get() >= 2) && (pressure.get() <= 8) );
}
```

The problem is that when I try this on my xml, this function (isPressureValid) is executed only once at the beginning. This is my xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="@dimen/visit_report_item_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/agro_item_height"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        bind:setEditTextColor="@{field.agroValuesModel.pressureValidation}"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:id="@+id/agro_row_pressure"


android:text="@=field.agroValuesModel.pressure}"android:textColor="@{field.agroValuesModel.isPressureValid() ? @color/colorPrimary : @color/main_color_accent_red}"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

I already tried using a boolean called "pressureValidation" and use notifyPropertyChanged(BR.pressureValidation) on the pressure setter and later use this on android:textColor like this:

```
android:textColor="@{field.agroValuesModel.pressureValid ? @color/colorPrimary : @color/main_color_accent_red}"
```

but this didn't work also. It seems that the setter of pressure ObservableInt variable is not used. Anyone has any tips on this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a POJO for this. Just create your view model with the bindable property you need. `ObservableInt` does everything for you and is handled as if it was an `int`.

```
public class Pressure {
    public final ObservableInt value = new ObservableInt();
}
```

In your layout you then only need to set `binding:textValue="@={pressure.value}"`. Using `android:text` would be possible too, but not too good, because setting an `int` to it should stay the default behavior.

```
@BindingAdapter("textValue")
public static void bindIntegerInText(TextView text, int value) {
    text.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    // Set the cursor to the end of the text
    text.setSelection(text.getText().length());
}
```

If you want to use the validation for the text color, you'd have to use an observable expression there as well. In you case it gets evaluated exactly once at the beginning, because the databinding doesn't know anything about the value underlying your validation.

You could add an `ObservableBoolean isValid` to `Pressure` and update its value anytime the `value` changes. For this you can register your own [`Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback.html) to `value` and set `isValid` in there.

Answer (score 0):

To reference the object itself in XML not the getter method when using a ObservableX object:

```
ObservableMap<String, Object> item = new ObservableArrayMap<>();
item.put("price", "$33.41");
```

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text='@{item["price"]}'/>
```

Or extend the BaseObservable and use a getter:

```
public class Item extends BaseObservable {
    private String price;

    @Bindable
    public String getPrice() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.price);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@{item.price}"/>
```